# Extended Monitors on Dell Laptop

Tags: laptop, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm trying to set up dual monitors to use with my laptop when I'm working in my home office. The goal being that I could not use my laptop screen itself, but have an extended desktop across 2 23" monitors that I have.

On my laptop I have the following:
- HDMI x1
- USB x2
- USB Type C x1

I purchased [this device](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A2E1MQA), which allows me to connect one monitor via one of the USB ports. This still utilizes the laptop screen though. I'm wondering, is my best bet to just purchase another one of these, or what is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

This would be used for light computing/web development work. Nothing graphics intensive. Not doing any heavy graphic design or anything.

EDIT:

Laptop is a Dell Inspiron 7569.
Screens are HP Elite Display E231

EDIT 2:

For anyone who finds this in the future, I ended up having problems with the accepted answer and finally purchased the Dell D3100 docking station which works flawlessly. I now have 3 extended monitors, which is exactly what I wanted.

[https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Display-Docking-Station-D3100/dp/B00O0M46KO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O0M46KO)

Comment: What is the laptop model? What are the monitors' models? How do you connect them to the laptop now? Can't help much with such un-specific question.

Comment: I added the additional info.

Comment: I did mention that I connect one of the monitors via the device I linked to into the USB port on my laptop. The other end goes into the DVI input on my monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still too little details.

First of all the monitor specs detail DP, DVI and VGA connections. How do you connect second monitor? HDMI2DP adapter? Cable? Kind of important as it is often the cause of the problems with multi-display setups - cable/adapter is faulty or incompatible with display and/or computer. which is why you might be having trouble setting it all up.

My recommendation would be to use HDMI-to-DVI cable (I'm using Amazon Basics and they're working fine on my setup) for one display and second monitor should be working using the existing USB2DVI adapter.

If you have, as specification shows for this laptop, Intel HD520 GPU then you can use up to three displays, thus you should be able to have desktop extended to the laptop display and both monitors. However, Dell might limit that to two simultaneous displays, so do not be surprised if there will be less options than desired.

But make sure you have up to date display drivers and connect all external displays wen laptop is powered on and you're logged in (allegedly windows 10 doesn't require it, unlike windows 7/8, but it won't hurt, either)

When your external displays are detected, recognized and enabled in the Screen Resolution settings (as Jelle described), you can set them however you like in it and you're good to go.

Comment: The monitors have display port, DVI, and VGA connections. For the current device I'm using, I'm going out from my laptop via USB port into the device, and then that converts to DVI which goes into the DVI port on one of my monitors.

Comment: So you're saying the combination of the graphics adapter I currently have for one monitor, and then the HDMI2DP cable for the other monitor will do it? Did I need the graphics adapter in the first place?

Comment: Yes. The adapter you have is enough to connect second screen, but I changed my recommendation to buy HDMI2DVI cable. HDMI2DP can only be done with adapters which can be a bit expensive. ANd the adapter you have already should allow you to connect both displays to it, but I recommend against it - the quality may suffer. ANd no, no need for graphics adapter (this term is synonym with video card, which you already have, obviously), unless you mean something else by it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also get video on the HP monitors?

You should have the option to select the behaviour of each monitor:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution

There you can select on which monitors to view.

A different approach is to get a hdmi splitter 1x2.

It should give the same outcome.

Kr

Comment: so I can split an HDMI signal out of my laptop into 2 monitors? that seems like a cleaner solution than this graphics adapter I bought. And that would accomplish an extended desktop across both monitors? I'm not concerned with being able to use the laptop monitor when it's hooked up, I'd only want to use both the HP monitors.

Comment: to be clear, i don't want the same thing displayed on 2 monitors, i want an extended desktop. From quickly looking at the splitter option, it appears to only display the same thing on 2 monitors.